# Python+Django : I cannot see my rendered data in checkout but I am able to see it in other pages

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this code:

```
{% for items in items%}

<div class="cart-row">
    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>x {{item.quantity}}</p></div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

[checkout.html](https://github.com/baibhabchakraborty/django-ecommerce/blob/master/store/templates/store/checkout.html)

I do not seem to be able to render out the information in checkout.html, but I did so in cart.html using the same code.

[Views.py](https://github.com/baibhabchakraborty/django-ecommerce/blob/master/store/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_Cart_total' : 0, 'get_cart_items' : 0}

    context = {'items' : items, 'order' : order}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_Cart_total' : 0, 'get_cart_items' : 0}

    context = {'items' : items, 'order' : order}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

[models.py](https://github.com/baibhabchakraborty/django-ecommerce/blob/master/store/models.py)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default = False, null = True, blank = False)
    image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default = False, null = True, blank = False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

[cart.html](https://github.com/baibhabchakraborty/django-ecommerce/blob/master/store/templates/store/cart.html)
In cart.html, I used the same tags and objects and it worked correctly without issues, but somehow it doesn't seem to work in checkout.html.
Please help me out in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for items in items%}

<div class="cart-row">
    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>x {{item.quantity}}</p></div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

I Think you made a typo, replace `items` to `item` in for loop

```
{% for item in items%}

<div class="cart-row">
    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price}}</p></div>
    <div style="flex:1"><p>x {{item.quantity}}</p></div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Sorry I can't comment, due to lack of reputation

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! It's working now!